# Paginating Eager loaded relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to paginate eager loaded results in Laravel

```
$sales  = Drinks::with('users', 'users.profile')
->where('id', $drink_id)->latest()->paginate(50);
```

Presently the results don't paginate.

Comment: which one you want to paginate? Drinks or relations?

Comment: Hi @Christian The relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i thought of 2 methods

1st method

//here returned as `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` not `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` so you need to make an extra logic to get current and next page from max relations etc.
to access it route('your_route', ['pagination_name'=>1])

```
$sales  = Drinks::with(['users' => function ($filter) {
  $filter->paginate(50, ['*'], 'pagination_name');
}])
->where('id', $drink_id)->first(); //latest() from unique id is first() or Drinks::find($drink_id);
```

i suggest this method, easier i guess

```
$sales  = Drinks::find($drink_id);
$sales->setRelation('user', $sales->users()->paginate(50)); //you can also set pagination name here
```

to use it : primary info use `$sales`, then to get pagination links use `$sales->user->links()` and `$sales->user` to list current paginated users

the rest is up to you to change the functionality

---

addition for response, in your model you can set attributes:

```
class User extends Model
{
  protected $with = ['profile'];
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian this works but it doesn't load the profile relationship, the users have a hasOne relationship with 'profile'

Comment: I'm actually sending the data as json to a Vue frontend, i can see all data except the profile..

Comment: added additional in answer